# Spinning Div using css3 animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I just need some help tweeking my code. I have created a css animation spinning a div. It spins 3 divs sized w-400 by h-300 pixels using a center axis. However when I resize the div the spinning axis is not centered as you can see in the JSFiddle. My code is below.

[JSFiddle for spinning div](http://jsfiddle.net/4p6Lk/11/)

*MY CSS*

```
 .hover-img {
            position: relative;
            width: 600px;
            height: 200px;
            -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            background:url(http://www.wholesaleforeveryone.com/content/images/blank/600/solid_color.gif);
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                line-height:600px;
            text-align:center;
            font-size:0;
            margin: 0 auto;
 }
.hover-img:hover{
           -webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);
            font-size:14px;
            color:white;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="row row2">
    <div class="column"><div class="hover-img"><p></p><img src="bottomleft.png" width="600" height="400" /> </div></div>
    <div class="column"><div class="hover-img"><p></p><img src="bottomright.png" width="600" height="400" /></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, add `margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: yes Mr_Green is correct. Add `margin : 0 auto` in `.hover-img `

Comment: @Prashant please look at my live demo as this is not the problem, look at the 5 divs, the top 3 spin fine but the bottom two move as they spin :) http://www.mildenhire.com/bigsmile/graphic.html

Comment: You need to change the width of .hover-img to max-width and give the child img max-width: 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please changes your css for `hover-img` class

```
.hover-img {
position: relative;
height: 300px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
background: url(bbclike/topright.png);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
line-height: 200px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Remove blank paragraph. From child class of  `class="hover-img"`